# How to connect buttons frame?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have three buttons, all have different direction. 
I have to connect them with a red line.

Just like Tic Tec Toc if game over than how to connect them with line:

*How do I set line between them??*

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do so. QuartzCore is one way.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do this with  QuartzCore ? or give some example if possible.

Comment: highly recommend you to try it yourself first. At least show us some of your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of drawing line :

Here you need to subclass UIView and then use CoreGraphics calls in the drawRect method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 25, 25);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 75, 75);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

}
```

Another way is using UIBezierPath as follows :

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(10.0, 10.0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)];

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];

[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

Comment: better to give more information of above. By overriding the `drawRect` function of `UIView`, you can draw simple patterns (like a line) on the context.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this code..

```
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, self.view.bounds.size.width, 1)];

lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[self.view addSubview:lineView];
```